# How to make a list of numbers from a txt file in python?

Tags: python

I have text file containing the numbers 52, 2,103,592,2090,34452,0,1, but arranged as one column (under each other). I want to import the numbers into python and create a list

```
L=[52,2,103,592,2090,34452,0,1]
```

The best I have managed to do so far is:

```
txtfile=open('file.txt')

L=[]
for line in txtfile:
    L.append(line.rstrip())

print(L)
```

which returns:

```
L=['52','2','103','592','2090','34452','0','1']
```

but the ' around the numbers bother me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should try using list comprehension and "with" keyword to make sure you don't forget to close the file.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    l = [int(line) for line in f]
print(l)
```

Comment: You don't need to slice; `int` can disregard the newline by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them to integers using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
txtfile=open('file.txt')

L=[]
for line in txtfile:
    L.append(int(line.rstrip()))
txtfile.close()
print(L)

[52, 2, 103, 592, 2090, 34452, 0, 1]
```

Comment: this is legacy code, right? why is not possible to use `with open`?

Comment: It *is* possible to use `open` and I would also suggest using it. This answer was written such that it has minimum difference from original code.

Comment: its been a while since i programmed in python. i am aware of the supposed advantages of `with`, which, to my understanding, is the fact that the file closes itself. so there are still situations in which only `open` by itself is preferred and suggested?

Comment: @oldboy My previous comment is missing a word. Let me rewrite it: "It *is* possible to use **`with open`** and I would also suggest using it. This answer was written such that it has minimum difference from original code" I hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: "*... so there are still situations in which only open by itself is preferred and suggested?*" In 90% of the cases, using `with` statement is far more better. Only exception that comes to my mind is the case where you are going to use the file for a long time (i.e. you'll write too much code under `with` statement), you can use `f = open(...)` so that you don't have to indent a long code block. Even in this situation, it is probably better to split the code into smaller pieces and write functions to do the job. So you can still use `with open` and it won't look ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int()` to convert string to integer, but I'd also like to emphasize using `with` keyword for handling files.

```
L = []
with open('file.txt') as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        L.append(int(line.rstrip()))
```

**Edit**: You can also read without `for` loop, by using `map` and `split` like so:

```
with open('file.txt') as txtfile:
    L = list(map(int, txtfile.read().split('\n')))
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to the other answers.

Comment: You don't need to call `read`; a file is already iterable, so you can just write `map(int, txtfile)`. `int` knows to strip leading and trailing whitespace (including newlines) from a `str` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Asocia's answer, but I would define the length of the list first (this may slightly increase speed, and is arguably a better practice):

```
txtfile=open('file.txt')

L = [0] * len(list(txtfile))

for lineIdx, line in enumerate(txtfile):
    L[lineIdx] = line.rstrip()

print(L)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
with open('s.txt') as num:
    numbers = num.read()
    n= numbers.split()
    lst = []
    for x in range(len(n)):
        nu = n[x]
        lst.append(int(nu))
    print(lst)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
txtfile=open('file.txt')
L=[]
for line in txtfile:
    L.append(line.rstrip())

a = L[0].split(',')
print sorted(a, key = int)
```

much better if you closed that file while opening using with

```
with open('file.txt') as txtfile:

     b = [x for x in txtfile]
     c = b[0].split(',')
     print sorted(list(map(int, c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to covert them to Integers, you can use the int(string) function in Python.

```
txtfile=open('file.txt')

L=[]
for line in txtfile:
    L.append(int(line.rstrip()))

print(L)
```

According to the official Python documentation, a shorter and "more elegant" solution if you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use list(f) or f.readlines().

```
yourList = open("filename.txt").readlines()
```

*Just as a recomendation:*

Also you might want to consider storing data on an a JSON file. The good thing about it, is that you can use it to communicate between applications that are written in another language.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json):

> Python allows you to use the popular data interchange format called JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). The standard module called json can take Python data hierarchies, and convert them to string representations; this process is called serializing. Reconstructing the data from the string representation is called deserializing. Between serializing and deserializing, the string representing the object may have been stored in a file or data, or sent over a network connection to some distant machine.

Answer (score 0):

- *but the ' around the numbers bother me* : Use `int(string, base)`

  > Returns an integer value, which is equivalent of binary string in the given base.Check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-int-function/)! for more
- *but arranged as one column (under each other)*
- *which returns L=['52','2','103','592','2090','34452','0','1']*

### Assumptions:

- numbers arranged `under each other` without commas that returns `['52','2','103','592','2090','34452','0','1']` as per the question

file.txt:

```
52
2
103
592
2090
34452
0
1
```

### Answer:

- imagine file.txt has 1000 numbers.

#### Approach 1: Use List as mentioned in the question

```py
print([int(i.rstrip()) for i in open('file.txt')])
```

**Size in memory**

- putting all numbers into a list would take 9032 bytes

### Suggestion

#### Approach 2: Use Generator

```py
print(*(int(i.rstrip()) for i in open('file.txt')))
```

**Size in memory**

- putting all 1000 numbers into a generator would take just 80 bytes.
- iterable like a list, but way more memory efficient, enclosed in plain parantheses `()`

#### Cons

- Access by index not possible with generators

```
print(g[4])   # TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

### Conclusion

- if you want to just keep the numbers in the memory and want to iterate over it whenever necessary, the recommended way is to go with generators as its memory efficient
- if want to access generators by index you can always convert a generator into a list like this `list(generator)`

Hope this helps!